# if the method" [aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(fun)]"'s fun had three parameter

Tags: ios

some one can tell me

I used this method "[aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(fun)]" to find if there was a fun in any class

but when the fun had three parameter how can i deal with it??

thanks

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In the selector each colon (:) is a parameter. for method `- (id)funWithA:(id)a B:(id)b C:(id)c`

```
[aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(funWithA:B:C:)];
```

If there is no text between the parameters `- (id)fun:(id)a :(id)b :(id)c`

```
[aClass respondsToSelector:@selector(fun:::)];
```